# IIS on 64-bit Windows Server 2012 won't run ElasticBeanstalk-Deployed WCF Application

Tags: wcf, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have an application written in WCF and deployed on IIS using AWS ElasticBeanstalk from within Visual Studio.

When I run target the uri of the WCF application (for testing) on a web browser, I get the error message that one of my DLLs or its dependency cannot be found. The DLL is a 64-bit binary and IIS is running a 64-bit windows operating system. The WCF project itself is also configured to target a 64-bit machine.

When I look into the folder of the deployed application on the server, I see the .svc file, wen.config file and the a bin folder. The bin folder indeed contains the dll in question even though IIS reports that it can't find it.

Should it be looking for it in bin/x64 folder instead, since I am only 'almost' sure that the application is being deployed as 64-bit. I have also tried enabling and disabling the Allow32Bit option on IIS, still no effect.

Please could you kindly tell me what I am doing wrong and guide me?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now resolved. It was dependency issues on native libraries which IIS could not detect automatically. Dependency Walker proved helpful in finding this out.